# how do I handle relay and graphql authentication if user is not logged in?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, graphql-js

I have schema that is configured to query for users' data when logged in but I don't know what to do with it when a user is not logged in, this is the root query:

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    viewer: {
      type: GraphQLUser,
      resolve: (root, args, { user }) => getViewer(), // I have a user data configured on requests if it's logged in
    },
    node: nodeField,
  },
});
```

I also have this error because I think there's no user data on rootValue yet so my query is returning undefined:

> Error: User.todoLists field type must be Output Type but got:
>   undefined.

If I return on the viewer the 'guest' text it wouldn't be a GraphQLUser type, help?

Answer (score 0):

You can return `null`.

If in the future you want to enforce non-null values, then you will have to use [GraphQLNonNull](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlnonnull) in your type definition, like this:

```
...
type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLUser),
...
```